# Does Docker Swarm keep data synced among nodes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I've never done anything with Docker Swarm, or Kubernetes so I'm trying to learn what does what, and which is best for my purpose before tackling it.

**My scenario:**

- I have a Desktop PC running Docker Desktop, and ..
- I have a Raspberry PI running Docker on Raspbian

This is all on a home LAN, so I don't really want to get crazy with complicated things.

I want to run Pi Hole and DNSCrypt Proxy containers on both 'machines', (as redundancy, mostly because the Docker Desktop seems to crash a lot taking down my entire DNS system with it when I just use that machine for Pi-hole).

My main thing is, I want all the data/configurations, etc. between them to stay in sync (i.e. Pi hole's container data stays in sync on both devices, etc.), and I want the manager to make sure it's always up, in case of crashes, and so on.

**My questions:**

Being completely new to this area, and just doing a bit of poking around:

- it seems that Kubernetes might be a bit much, and more complicated than I need for this?
- That's why I was thinking Swarm instead, but I'm also not sure whether either of them will keep data synced?
- And, say I create 2 Pi-hole containers on the Manager machine, does it create 1 on the manager machine, and 1 on the worker machine?

Any info is appreciated!

Comment: When you say 'data' do you mean that stuff on the containers is changing over time based on the the traffic they see and you want a copy of that to follow the container around, or do you mean you have a set of data that you set when you first start the container that will never change (like a config file)? My guess for those two applications is that their probably pretty stateless, but I

Comment: @CantankerousBullMoose The former. Basically, any data that changes in either container (for example 1 node on both a manager machine, and a worker machine) gets sysnced and saved. Example: I have a Pi-hole container on each machine, and I change a setting on 1 machine, such as add an IP to blacklist and click Save, I want it to save that on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't quite have anything that directly meets your need, but if you've got a reliable file server on your home LAN, you could do it really easily.

Broadly speaking you want to look at [Docker Volume Plugins](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/#volume-plugins). Most of them ultimately work via an external storage provider and so won't be that helpful for you. There's a couple of more exotic ones like Portworx or StorageOS that can do portable/replicated storage purely in Docker, but I think most of them are a paid license.

But, if you have a fileserver that you trust to stay up and running, you can mount an NFS/CIFS share as a volume as mentioned in the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options), and Docker can handle re-connecting it when a container moves from one node to another due to a failure.

One other note: you want two manager nodes and one container per service in your swarm. You need to have one working Manager node for the swarm to work (this is important if a Manager crashes). Multiple separate instances would generally only be helpful if the service was designed as a distributed/fault tolerant application.